# Why can't I run ASP.NET Core 3.1 on IIS with hosting bundle version6.0.4?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I'm running ASP.NET Core 6 Web API on IIS with installed hosting bundle for .NET 6. The Web API is running fine.

Now I published an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app and tried to host the it on the same IIS, but I got:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure

Is the .NET 6 hosting bundle backward-compatible to ASP.NET Core 3.1? What should I do to make both apps run in the same IIS? Thanks

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 reached end of life, so nobody is there to ensure compatibility. To you, the only feasible solution is to upgrade to .NET 6 or 7.

Comment: You need install the corresponding hosting buddle for each project you want to run on IIS.

Comment: @Rena are you saying that technically it is possible to host net 3.1 and .net 6 apps on the same IIS instance?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the hosting model in the Web.config file from "outofprocess" to "inprocess".
You can read more about the hosting model:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/in-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-7.0
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/out-of-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-7.0
3. https://www.sharepointcafe.net/2022/05/inprocess-and-outofprocess-hosting-model.html